# Using pointer to a struct to create linked list and Memory allocation in C

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, structure

I have a concept question I suppose.  When I need to create a linked list, but I am just given a pointer to a struct (and the struct contains some data type and pointer "next").  How would I ensure that I am creating the other links and not just the root node?  I am not using malloc or else this would be more apparent answer. This list is acting as malloc itself.

Thanks in advance!

**To Clarify:**

There will be single dimension array which will act as a block of memory of fixed sized.  The linked list will then "allocate" by removing a node and putting it into the array or "free" data by removing it from array to add back to list.

**example**

(struct defined by some data type and pointer)
struct is called node

```
node array[10];  //this acts as memory
node* linked_list;  //this gives or removes data to memory (array)
```

Comment: If there is just one root as for `malloc`, you can use a global variable for the root and test whether it is NULL. The question is unclear…

Comment: excuse - I have clarified question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to how we did things in my Data Structures class using FORTRAN 77 (back in the mid-Cretaceous); we allocated a fixed-size array and used it as our memory pool.

Basically, you have to maintain a "free" list; these are the nodes that are available for use.  When you first start up, you initialize each element in your array to explicitly point to the next element:

```
struct node {T data; struct node *next; } pool[N]; // for some type T
...
for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
  pool[i].next = &pool[i+1];
pool[i].next = NULL;
```

Your free list initially points to the first element in the pool:

```
struct node *free = &pool[0];
```

When you allocate a node, you retrieve the element that `free` points to, update `free` to point to the next available element in the list (if one exists), then initialize the element as necessary:

```
if (free) // is there a free node available
{
  struct node *newNode = free;
  free = free->next;
  newNode->data = ...;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  ...
}
```

When you're done with a node, you add it back to the head of the `free` list:

```
node->next = free;
free = node;
```

Naturally, real code would be better organized than this, but this should be enough to give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: +1, that's definitively better than having a "flag" field in the node `struct`.

Comment: I have made these changes and used this idea - if I get a segmentation fault when I am freeing up more than one node, why would that happen? (Sorry if this is vague)  I am looping to add new nodes then looping to remove some.

Comment: @abitlost: a segfault sounds like either a `next` pointer hasn't been properly initialized, or you're trying to dereference a NULL pointer, or something like that.  Let me update my answer to present something a little more robust.

Comment: @abitlost: Actually, now that I think of it, make sure you're not clobbering the next pointer before you update the free list.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure if this applies to your particular question, but I do would like to point out something about creating a linked list without using `malloc`.

It doesn't really matter how you allocate the nodes of the linked list, be it dynamically or statically. What matters is that every node actually exists and the pointers are valid.

For example, we can build a linked list from an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_t {
    int value;
    struct node_t *next;
} node;

int main() {

    int i;
    node linked_list[10];

    // build the linked list
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        linked_list[i].value = i * i;
        linked_list[i].next = ( i < 9 ) ? &linked_list[i+1] : 0;
    }

    // now traverse it
    node *head = &linked_list[0];
    while ( head ) {
        printf( "%d\n", head->value );
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: in order to use an array as the place from which to "allocate" or "free" the linked list nodes, you can augment the node `struct` with a flag to indicate if the node is being used or not.

```
typedef struct node_t {
    char in_use;
    int value;
    struct node_t *next;
} node;
```

**EDIT2**: let's give it one last try. Below is the function that "allocates" one node from the array (or returns `NULL` if none is available). Assume `linked_list` is global.

```
node *get_node() {
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        if ( !linked_list[i].in_use ) {
            linked_list[i].in_use = true;
            return &linked_list[i];
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT3**: if the array is to be used as a memory pool the way to go is John Bode's answer.

Comment: Yes the problem I am coming to is ensuring each node of the list exists. But for the array I am sure.  I used this for loop to do so. The pointer to the struct needs to have nodes but I am not sure they exist. Let us say we add:  node* ptr; and this is supposed to have same number of nodes as the array you gave. How would I create each node for the pointer to make linked list?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. The nodes are either already allocated or not. How is it that you're not certain?

Comment: 'int i;
    node linked_list[10];  
    node* ptrLinkedList; //create linked list using this 
        // build the linked list
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            linked_list[i].value = i * i;
            linked_list[i].next = ( i < 9 ) ? &linked_list[i+1] : 0;
        }'

Comment: Ok, so what is that you want, to create another linked list equal to the one pointed to by `head`, or something else?

Comment: the head should just remove a link at a time to put into array. not for traversing. it seems like I did not create more than one link. how do I know it is a full linked list and not just root node?

Comment: Okay maybe I see - in your code: node* head = &linked_list[0]; does this create a linked with all elements of array? If so my problem is that I have mis-created list.

Comment: Yes! Okay this was my misunderstanding. Sorry for the run-around. So when head points to array, it will have all elements. And can then use those elements such as head.next? Yes Thank You.

Comment: Well, glad that helped! Don't forget to accept an answer (you can click on the green check mark next to the answer) ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible scenarios:

- The linked list is using malloc. The linked list is then responsible for the allocation and de-allocation of nodes. This is the standard implementation.
- The linked list is using a statically allocated chunk of memory, ie a static array of fixed size. Such a linked list is more complex, as you would have to keep track of which parts of the array that contain data. You will also need to keep track of the linked list size.
- The linked list is an "array of nodes with index lookup table". It is then not allocating any data, but instead every node contains contains array indices. The linked list will need to keep track of the list size.
- The linked list is not performing any allocation. Allocation is done by the caller (statically or dynamically). In this case the linked list only keeps track of the next pointers and allocates nothing. This version is poor object-oriented design, as it breaks the private encapsulation of data.

EDIT after op change:
Seems you are using version 3 above then. Google for "linked list using array" or similar.

Comment: The #2 is more like my problem - the linked list is using an array of fixed size